# out of range python lists although it is not

Tags: python-3.x

```
guests = ['yara', 'fatma', 'hamdi', 'monica', 'mirna']
cannot_make_it = ['hamdi', 'monica', 'mirna']


guests.pop()
guests.pop()
guests.pop()
guests.append('mona')
guests.append('nour')


guests.insert(0, 'salma')
guests.insert(3, 'koko')
guests.append('soso')

guests.pop(2)
guests.pop(3)
guests.pop(4)
guests.pop(5)
guests.pop(6)

print('Only the following can come due to shortage in places:')
print(guests[0])
print(guests[1])

print('Sorry, ' + guests.pop(2) + ' you cannot come.')
print('Sorry, ' + guests.pop(3) + ' you cannot come.')
print('Sorry, ' + guests.pop(4) + ' you cannot come.')
print('Sorry, ' + guests.pop(5) + ' you cannot come.')
print('Sorry, ' + guests.pop(6) + ' you cannot come.')
```

the error message is:
"D:\pythonProject\3-7  shrinking guest list\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "D:/pythonProject/3-7  shrinking guest list/shrinking guest list.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/pythonProject/3-7  shrinking guest list/shrinking guest list.py", line 19, in 
guests.pop(5)
IndexError: pop index out of range

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you're doing pop(5), there isn't any element in that index because the guest list has been shrinking from the previous 3 pops.